# Problem trying to detour function with assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, detours

Just for the fun of it, I am trying to make a simple detouring library that will detour member functions by modifying the vtable of the class to create a detour. I am getting some odd behaviour. Here is the entire program (I am using MSVC++ 2010):

```
fixed
```

It's `jmp`ing to the address of the new function correctly, but it crashes after that. When I watch it in ollydbg to see why it's crashing, something very strange happens. It will walk right over some instructions without doing anything. Where I see a `push xxx` in the debugger, the stack will not be modified. Where I see a `retn 4` the thing will just keep going, into the space between functions, filled with `int 3`s. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

EDIT: Nevermind, I found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Turns out you have to subtract 5 from the address to calculate it correctly, since it's the relative address not from the end of the instruction but from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

for MSVC Microsoft Research has library called "Detours":
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/
You may want to use it since it is already available and I think 32 bit version is free.

Comment: The point was not to detour something, the point was to make my own detouring library. I already use Detours, but I wanted to make my own.

Comment: The whole "charge for 64-bit version" thing is a real turn-off for me, even more (somehow) than just the closed-source aspect.